# something about gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/DaikiMaekawa/hector_slam_example
https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam

1,roscore
2,roslaunch hector_slam_example hector_rplidar.launch
3,roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch

when I move the robot
Waiting for tf transform data between frames /map and /base_link to become available
[ERROR] [1464747037.885943685]: The plugin failed to load for some reason. Error: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class hector_geotiff_plugins/TrajectoryMapWriter with base class type hector_geotiff::MapWriterPluginInterface does not exist. Declared types are

[hector_mapping-9] process has died [pid 6941, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/hector_mapping/hector_mapping __name:=hector_mapping __log:=/home/ligang/.ros/log/6f406894-2799-11e6-b330-a088b48fb934/hector_mapping-9.log].
log file: /home/ligang/.ros/log/6f406894-2799-11e6-b330-a088b48fb934/hector_mapping-9*.log

[rospack] Warning: no such package hector_geotiff
[ERROR] [1464747326.998373367]: The plugin failed to load for some reason. Error: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class hector_geotiff_plugins/TrajectoryMapWriter with base class type hector_geotiff::MapWriterPluginInterface does not exist. Declared types are
[ INFO] [1464747326.998484746]: Geotiff node started

when i install https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam some question is ok.
but have another question.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235748/something-about-gmapping/) by [ligang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26953/ligang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

your question is about hectorslam,not gmapping.
rplidar has a default launch file with hectorslam that can run without any configuration,  it locate at [here](https://github.com/robopeak/rplidar_ros/tree/slam)

download it  it your catkin_ws/src , and put hectorslam sourcefiles  there too.

```
catkin_make
roslaunch rplidar view_slam.launch
```

that would probably works.

---

Originally posted by [panda](https://answers.ros.org/users/26909/panda/) with karma: 63 on 2016-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ligang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26953/ligang/) on 2016-06-05**:
Thanks for your help.
Now, it works well.
But, when the time is longer than somtimes, It will error.
I want to know that how can I scan more time
or the limit of the time or area.